Get Product Data Using Woocommerce API Returns Duplicates - Node Js
I am trying to fetch product data from my website using woocommerce-api library in node js.
I've tested that code is working as expected with other websites. However in my case I get a lot of product duplicates.
I did some manual checks ( /products?id= ) but there were no ID duplicates at all. Ended up with the conclusion that something is going wrong with page rendering.
Here is the code:
var WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');

var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
    url: 'https://my-website.com',
    consumerKey: 'ck_1234',
    consumerSecret: 'cs_1234',
    wpAPI: true,
    version: 'wc/v3'
  });


function displayProductDetails(product) {
    var selectedFields = {
        id: product.id,
        sku: product.sku,
        title: product.name,
        price: product.regular_price,
    };
}

async function fetchAllProducts() {
    let page = 1;
    let allProducts = [];
    let productSKUs = new Set();
    let productIDs = new Set();
    let stotalproducts = 0;

    while (true) {
        try {
            const result = await WooCommerce.getAsync(`products?per_page=100&page=${page}&orderby=id&order=asc`);

            await delay(1500);
            const data = JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);

            if (page === 1) {
                stotalproducts = result.headers['x-wp-total'];
                console.log(`Total Products: ${stotalproducts}`);
            }

            if (data.length === 0) {
                break;
            }

            console.log(`Fetched ${data.length} products from page ${page}`);
            let uniqueCount = 0;

            // Process and add products to the existing list if SKU and ID are unique
            data.forEach(product => {
                if (!productSKUs.has(product.sku) && !productIDs.has(product.id)) {
                    productSKUs.add(product.sku);
                    productIDs.add(product.id);
                    allProducts.push(product);
                    displayProductDetails(product);
                    uniqueCount++;
                } else {
                    console.log(`Duplicate found: SKU = ${product.sku}, ID = ${product.id}`);
                }
            });

            console.log(`Unique products added from page ${page}: ${uniqueCount}`);
            page++;
            await delay(3000);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log('Fetched products count:', allProducts.length);
    console.log('Unique SKUs count:', productSKUs.size);
    console.log('Unique IDs count:', productIDs.size);

    return allProducts;
}

function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
        setTimeout(resolve, time)
    });
  }

This specific website has a total of 5681 products. After removing duplicates, unique products count was something like 3650. After adding some delay in the whole process, unique products count was variable from 3200 to 4100.
Things I gave a try without luck:

Cache Disable
Limit products per page (?per_page=30)
Filter products order (orderby=id)
Updated WooCommerce plugin to latest version.

Any ideas on my issue would be highly appreciated. Thank you from you time in advance!

Changing the API version from v3 to v2 did the trick:
var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
url: 'https://my-website.com',
consumerKey: 'ck_1234',
consumerSecret: 'cs_1234',
wpAPI: true,
version: 'wc/v2'
});
